Most efficient way of finding specific coefficients of product of high-dimensional Fourier series
I find myself in need of an efficient way to perform a specific computation. Suppose I have the following two Fourier series
$$
a(t_1,t_2,t_3)=\sum_{j=-n}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=-n}^{n} a_{j,k,l} e^{ijt_1} e^{ikt_2} e^{ilt_3},         \qquad   b(t_1,0,t_3)=\sum_{j=-n}^{n} \sum_{l=-n}^{n} b_{j,0,l} e^{ijt_1} e^{ilt_3}.
$$
The product of these Fourier series is another Fourier series,
$$
(ab)(t_1,t_2,t_3)=\sum_{j=-2n}^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=-2n}^{2n} c_{j,k,l} e^{ijt_1} e^{ikt_2} e^{ilt_3}.
$$
Suppose what we want to compute is not the entire 3D Fourier series of the product $ab$ with all its coefficients, but rather only the coefficients $c_{j,k,0}$ defining the 2D Fourier series
$$
\sum_{j=-2n}^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_{j,k,0} e^{ijt_1} e^{ikt_2}.
$$
Using a 3D FFT would cost $O(n^3 \log(n))$ time. Can we do any better than that in terms of time complexity since we only want to compute the product coefficients with $l=0$ and there are only $O(n^2)$ of them? What is the fastest way that this can be done, and can it be done faster than $O(n^3 \log(n))$? Can it be done in $O(n^3)$ time? I thank all helpers.
